# Get Array containing indecies of matched strings outside HTML Tags - Python

Tags: python, html, string, beautifulsoup

say `string = "<html><body><h1>hello world</h1><p>I am super happy today</p></body></html>"`

Using BeautifulSoup, is there a way for me to get an array that store the indices of the char 'h' only if it was matched **outside** of a html tag?

`>>> [16, 46]`

Comment: you can use `contents` attribute. `for hit in soup.findAll():
       print hit.contents` Now you can count only matched outside of html tags.

Comment: neat, i'll try that

Comment: it just returns to contents of the string

Comment: I would like to get the indices of the match

Comment: I remember someone asking for this as well, not sure why you need it, I'll try to find it. I know it's also easy to do this with regex, will look for a solution with bs.